# Extracting whole line if a character is present at certain position

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am a java programmer and a newbie to shell scripting, I have a daunting task to parse multi gigabyte logs and look for lines where '1'(just 1 no qoutes) is present at 446th position of the line, I am able to verify that character 1 is present by running this `cat *.log | cut -c 446-446 | sort | uniq  -c`  but I am not able to extract the lines and print them in an output file.

Comment: updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '{if (substr($0,446,1) == "1") {print $0}}' file
```

is the basics.

You can use `FILENAME` in the print feature to add the filename to the output, so then you could do

```
awk '{if (substr($0,446,1) == "1") {print FILENAME ":" $0}}' file1 file2 ...
```

IHTH

Comment: would this be ok awk '{if (substr($0,446,1) == "1") {print FILENAME ":" $0}}' *.log > result.log  ?

Comment: @Shek: `awk 'substr($0, 446, 1) == "1" {print FILENAME ":" $0}' *.log* > result.log`

Answer (score 1):

You can use an awk command for that:

```
awk 'substr($0, 446, 1) == "1"' file.log
```

`substr` function will get 1 character at position `446` and `== "1"` will ensure that character is `1`.

Comment: What if there's another `1` before position 446?

Comment: how can I pipe this to an output file.

Comment: `awk 'substr($0, 446, 1) == "1"' file.log > file.out`

Comment: Actually I just realized @shellter has posted similar answer so I am deleting my answer and upvoting his solution.

Comment: Don't, he said he's a newbie (not @shellter :). More options is better.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding grep to the pipe:

`grep '^.\{445\}1.*$'`

Comment: The `.*$` can be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Another in awk. To make a more sane example, we print lines where the third char is 3:

```
$ cat file
123  # this
456  # not this
$ awk -F '' '$3==3' file
123  # this
```

based on that example but untested:

```
$ awk -F '' '$446==1' file
```